# Multiple View Controllers being loaded at the same time. iPhone app

Tags: iphone, json, view

I am trying to create an app that swipes over through multiple view controllers on a UIScrollView - similar to how one would see different windows in the safari app, but instead of tapping a button to move between them, I am swiping the scroll view.

Now, I will be getting notifications when any of the data in a particular view is to be updated with some json. Should I be updating the view that aren't showing (but are on the scroll view), or should I wait until the user scrolls to that view?

I am very concerned about performance here. Hopefully I am being clear in the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the views next to the view that you are viewing I would say. And when you switch (scroll) to another view, then update the views next to that view. (Assuming you have received new JSON data)